# Как взять значение поля "Имя" из контактной формы и вставить его в HTML thank you page

Tags: javascript, php

Я прошу прощение за глупый вопрос. Откровенно запостил его, чтобы быстрее найти ответ. Каким образом можно взять значение из поля Имя в контактной форме и вставить его в новую страницу HTML Thank you Page при помощи PHP или JavaScript?

Схематично то, что я хочу сделать выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что у вас конкретно не получается? Если по простому, то делаем форму с кнопкой и в параметре `action` путь к файлу который выводить ваше приветствие. И метод передачи, например `POST`. Соответственно вытаскиваем переменную так: `$_POST['ваше_имя_переменной']`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую